# Can "SSLVerifyClient" be specified in <Location /xxxx>?

Tags: apache, ssl

I have an Apache 2.4.48 instance that is configured for 2-way/client authentication, but we only want to request a client cert in a specific URI, e.g. we want something like this:

```
<VirtualHost...>
.
.
SSLVerifyClient none
.
.
<Location /abc>
SSLVerifyClient none
</Location>
.
.
<Location /xyz>
SSLVerifyClient optional
.
.
</Location>
.
.
</VirtualHost>
```

So:

- if there is a request for https://myhost.com/abc, then the userwouldn't be prompted for a client cert, but
- if there is a request
  for https://myhost.com/xyz, then the user would be prompted for a
  client cert

I thought that that should work, but when I test with a request to https://myhost.com/abc, I am getting the cert popup, i.e., it doesn't seem like Apache is "obeying" the "SSLVerifyClient none"?

I've also been reading some docs that seem to indicate that the "SSLVerifyClient" can only be used per-server or per-directory.  Does that mean that it cannot be used per-location?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I don't think that will work, as the SSL handshake has to be done *before* the client can send the request. At best you can depend on the hostname, if the client supports SNI (which I think most modern ones do). *Edit:* I stand corrected, it's possible with renegotiation, but that makes it complicated and prone to problems. So requiring certivicates on a certain hostname is probably easier to do and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out my problem...

The bottom line is that the SSLVerifyClient DOES work in .

My problem was I had the "SSLVerifyClient optional" on the wrong Location URL.  I had to add an additional  for the correct URL with an "SSLClientVerify optional" in it, and now it works as expected.